# Access Images from external storage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET site in a web server and the images are stored in NAS (some kind of lacie external storage), I tried UNC and other things but no success.

how can I access images from external storage in ASP.NET

Thanks

Update: The images are reachable from the server but when I try to access in ASP.NET throws me error.

Comment: That external storage should be available to your operational system; so you'll need to use a drive letter, or a valid UNC path.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever domain account / local account your web service is running under needs access to the UNC where the images are stored. Grant appropriate permissions (for example to the WebServer\ASPNET account).

Answer (score 1):

This is a file-system access and permissions issue, not an ASP.Net issue.  ASP.Net is dependent on the facilities on the local server, so there's nothing in ASP.Net to provide you access to external storage if the location is unreachable from your server.

Once you can reliably access the location through the file system, you can set about accessing the location through ASP.Net.